# Evaluating a line integral for a circular path

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-analysis

"Let $F(x,y) = x^2-y^2$. Evaluate:

$\oint \frac{\partial F}{\partial n}ds$ around the circle $x^2+y^2 = 1$. Here, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial n}$ is the directional derivative of $F$ along the outer normal and $dS$ = $|dS|$."

I can't use the fact that this is a conservative vector field. I know the answer should be $0$. I have to do the question using first principles. How would I go about doing this though? I know I have to parametrize the circle but how do I incorporate it into the integral? I am a little confused about that.

Can someone guide me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: If you parameterize the circle in the usual way the integrand simplifies greatly with the cosine double angle identity $\cos^2{t}-\sin^2{t}=\cos{2t}$

Comment: Hint: The derivative of $F$ in the direction of the unit vector $u$ is $\nabla F\cdot u$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a point on the unit circle, the unit normal vector would be $\hat{n} =(x,y)$.

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial n}= \nabla F \cdot \hat{n}=2x^2-2y^2$

Your integral would then become $\int_{c}(2x^2-2y^2)ds$.

Can you get it from here?

Comment: How did you get 
$\frac{\partial F}{\partial n}= \nabla F \cdot \hat{n}=2x^2-2y^2$? 

Sorry. It's been 5 years since I took multivariable calculus. I thought it would just be $<2x,2y>$.

Comment: $\nabla F = <2x,-2y>$ is the gradient of the function. The unit vector normal to the unit circle is $<x,y>$. $\frac{\partial F}{\partial n}$ is the projection of the gradient of F onto the unit normal, i.e. the dot product of those two things.

Comment: Only thing I want to note is that isn't a unit normal, you should also divide by its length though it won't matter in the grand scheme since the $|dS|$ term will bring another magnitude to cancel the denominator